# Cómo obtener más datos de SQL desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta es muy simple (soy nuevo en esto de la programación)

Tengo un código PHP que obtiene datos de mi base de datos SQL, es éste:

```
<?php
echo $db->returnSubscriptions();

?>
```

Todo funciona bien como se ve aquí:

[image: dd]

Pero necesito que dentro de `subscriptions` se obtenga el valor de `packageid`.

**Aquí una screenshot para entrar en contexto:**
[image: Screenshot]

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
**CÓDIGO RETURNSUBSCRIPTIONS:**

```
function returnSubscriptions() {
    $htmlCode = "";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
      $user = new User($row['userid'], $this);
      $package = new Package($row['packageid'],$this);




      $htmlCode .= '
      <tr>
       <th scope="row">'.$row['id'].'</th>
       <td>'.$user->getData('username').'</td>
       <td>'.str_replace("-",".",$row['date']).'</td>
       <td>'.str_replace("-",".",$row['expires']).'</td>
       <td>'.$package->getName().'</td>
       <td><a href="?del='.$row['id'].'"><span class="badge badge-danger">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a></td>
      </tr>';
    }

    return $htmlCode;
  }
```

Aclaro que usando el código obtiene TODOS los datos, y que el `packageid` es una suscripción especifica a la cual el sistema le asigna el ID.

Lo que busco es que **en vez de obtener TODOS los datos, solo obtenga la suscripción especifica que tenga el usuario.**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si los campos que se muestran en la parte baja de la imagen son todos los que tiene esa tabla, solo tienes que cambiar la query de `SELECT * FROM subscriptions`
a `SELECT packageid FROM subscriptions`.

El dónde exactamente? No te sabría decir ya que falta código, pero con ese cambio debería sacar lo que tú quieres.

**EDIT:**

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1");
```

debería ser

```
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT userid, packageid FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1");
```

Ya que estamos, estás preparando un sentencia SQL con datos
estáticos, la sentencia no cambia nunca, con lo que podrías hacer

```
$stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT userid, packageid FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1");
```

y borrar la linea

```
$stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT 2:** Según los comentarios y las imagenes, faltaba el userid en la select, editado conforme a ello.

**EDIT 3:** Vistas las aclaraciones, como bien apuntaba markvegas, la consulta debería cambiarse para que sólo devuelva a un usuario. Con lo anteriormente ya establecido, la consulta quedaría así

```
SELECT packageid FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1 AND userid = '$usuario'
```

Una opción sería pasar el usuario del que quieres las suscripciones en el método returnSubscriptions. El código quedaría así:

```
function returnSubscriptions($usuario) {
$htmlCode = "";
$stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT userid, packageid FROM subscriptions WHERE active = 1 AND userid = '$usuario'");
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
  $user = new User($row['userid'], $this);
  $package = new Package($row['packageid'],$this);




  $htmlCode .= '
  <tr>
   <th scope="row">'.$row['id'].'</th>
   <td>'.$user->getData('username').'</td>
   <td>'.str_replace("-",".",$row['date']).'</td>
   <td>'.str_replace("-",".",$row['expires']).'</td>
   <td>'.$package->getName().'</td>
   <td><a href="?del='.$row['id'].'"><span class="badge badge-danger">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a></td>
  </tr>';
}

return $htmlCode;
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127484/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-petrov-como-obtener-mas-datos-de-sql-desde-php).

Answer (score -1):

Deberías hacer la siguiente consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions
WHERE userid = aqui el id del usuario que buscas
```

De esta forma te devuelve los los datos de la suscripción que pertenece a un usuario específico.

Comment: Disculpa bro y eso cómo lo paso a php? es decir, que pueda consultarlo desde php